# Rename Taxonomy label in editor bolt-cms

Tags: bolt-cms

I would like to rename the default tab value of Taxonomy in the backend page editor. I didn't find anything in the twig or yml files that would address this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I checked with bolt developers and there is no way currently to do this. One potential option was to use the messages file but it was not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

As you can imagine, since this isn't supported via the public configs, this will need a bit more advanced plugging together.

Here is a way to add an additional resource to the stack of translations.

https://gist.github.com/rossriley/c74fdee4fec3eaffb12f

This is a technique to add your own messages onto the translation stack without touching the underlying core files.

After creating this, you'll need to add your new service provider to the app, which you normally will bootstrap either in your index.php or a custom bootstrap file.